# Password protecting a page (node) in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, password-protection

I have Drupal 7 site and i need to add one page (node) that is password protected. Because this is one time thing, i'd prefer not to use those pretty complicated access control modules in Drupal.

Any ideas, how to restrict access for a node? Can i somehow use user roles for this? It would be perfect, but seems not to work out-of-box.

Comment: Suggestion: Create another role and assign people you want to have access to the "password" protected page to that role. Only really works if you have a small website.

Comment: How to limit page to certain role only? I can do it for blocks, but not for pages?

Comment: Here's a link to a question I asked a while ago about that subject. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39002/set-a-page-to-show-only-to-registered-users

Comment: As an alternative: select `php code` as a `text format` while creating your node and enter something like this: `<?php if(isset($_POST['pwd']) && $_POST['pwd'] == $pwd) { echo $protected_content; } else { echo 'Enter password: <br /><form method="POST" action=""><input type="password" name="password" /><input type="submit" /></form>'; }` Notice: it's not a working code, just as an idea.

Answer (score 1):

```
function theme_preprocess_node( &$variables )
{
    $allowed_roles = array("administrator", "media");

    global $user;
    if($variables['nid'] == NODEID)
    {
        foreach($user->roles as $role)
        {
            if(in_array($role, $allowed_roles))
                return;
        }
        drupal_goto("user"); //  redirect to login
    }
}
```

I used solution above to handle this situation. It was best solution for me, although it's not very verbose for user :)